# Python Trouble with find_all()

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am attempting to scrape a site for for some data on an long list of items.  Below is my code:

```
def find_info():
    page = requests.get(URL)
    soup = bs(page.content, 'html.parser')
    soup2 = bs(soup.prettify(), "html.parser")
    lists = soup2.find_all('div', class_="featured_item")

    #with open('data.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
    #    thewriter = writer(f)
    #    header = ['Rank', 'Number', 'Price'] #csv: comma separated values
    #    thewriter.writerow(header)

    for list in lists:
        stats = lists.find_all('div', class_="item_stats")
        sale = lists.find('div', class_="sale")

        rank = float(stats.select('.item_stats span')[0].text)
        number = stats.select('.item_stats span')[1].text.strip().replace('#', '')
        price = sale.select('span')[0].text.strip().replace('◎', '')
        print(rank, number, price)

    
find_info()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Cameron Lemon\source\repos\ScrapperGUI\module1.py", line 36, in <module>
find_info()
File "C:\Users\Cameron Lemon\source\repos\ScrapperGUI\module1.py", line 27, in 
find_info
stats = lists.find_all('div', class_="item_stats")
File "C:\Users\Cameron Lemon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\bs4\element.py", line 2253, in __getattr__
raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a 
list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call 
find()?
Press any key to continue . . .
```

This code runs well, until I add the line `for list in lists:` and use `find_all()` instead of `find()`.  I am very confused, because in the past I have coded to find data for the first item in the list successfully and then set a for loop and changed my find() to find_all(). Any advice is much appreciated.  Thank you

Below is my lists variable, for two of the many items within it.

```
[<div class="featured_item">
<div class="featured_item_img">
<a href="/degds/3251/">
<img src="URL"/>
 </a>
</div>
<div class="featured_image_desc" style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
<div class="item_stats">
<div class="item_stat">
          rank
          <span>
           1
          </span>
</div>
<div class="item_stat">
          item no.
          <span>
           #3251
          </span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="sale" style="height: 40px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
<span>
          not for sale
         </span>
  </div>
 <div class="last_sale" style="font-size: 11px;">
     no sale history
    </div>
</div>
</div>, <div class="featured_item">
<div class="featured_item_img">
 <a href="/dgds/8628/">
 <img src="URL"/>
</a>
</div>
<div class="featured_image_desc" style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
<div class="item_stats">
<div class="item_stat">
           rank
          <span>
           2
          </span>
</div>
<div class="item_stat">
      item no.
      <span>
       #8628
      </span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="sale" style="height: 40px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
<span>
         not for sale
        </span>
</div>
<div class="last_sale" style="font-size: 11px;">
         no sale history
       </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using find_all method two times. When you use for loop then you will get each item meaning list didn't exist any more. So we can't use find_all without list that's why you are getting that error.

```
html='''
<div class="featured_item">
<div class="featured_item_img">
<a href="/degds/3251/">
<img src="URL"/>
 </a>
</div>
<div class="featured_image_desc" style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
<div class="item_stats">
<div class="item_stat">
          rank
          <span>
           1
          </span>
</div>
<div class="item_stat">
          item no.
          <span>
           #3251
          </span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="sale" style="height: 40px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
<span>
          not for sale
         </span>
  </div>
 <div class="last_sale" style="font-size: 11px;">
     no sale history
    </div>
</div>
</div>, <div class="featured_item">
<div class="featured_item_img">
 <a href="/dgds/8628/">
 <img src="URL"/>
</a>
</div>
<div class="featured_image_desc" style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
<div class="item_stats">
<div class="item_stat">
           rank
          <span>
           2
          </span>
</div>
<div class="item_stat">
      item no.
      <span>
       #8628
      </span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="sale" style="height: 40px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
<span>
         not for sale
        </span>
</div>
<div class="last_sale" style="font-size: 11px;">
         no sale history
       </div>
</div>
'''


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

lists = soup.find_all('div', class_="featured_item")

for lis in lists:
    stats = lis.find('div', class_="item_stats")
    sale = lis.find('div', class_="sale")

    rank = float(stats.select('.item_stats span')[0].text)
    number = stats.select('.item_stats span')[1].text.strip().replace('#', '')
    price = sale.select('span')[0].text.strip().replace('◎', '')
    print(rank, number, price)
```

**Output:**

```
1.0 3251 not for sale
2.0 8628 not for sale
```